# eclipse ide doesn't update changes

Tags: java, eclipse, openhab

When i want to run my programm eclipse runs old code.
I cleaned the project and build it again but eclipse show me the old code when i want to debug it.
I my editor window i see the new code, but in the debug window there is old code.
This is the Window --> Preferences --> Run/ Debug --> Launing Window:

[image]

I installed eclipse from the officile eclipse/smarthome site and selected openHAB 2, OpenHAB 2 Bindings, eclipse smarhome and ESH Core (Does not know the exactly name of this repo) to clone from github.

When i open the files with the editor it shows me the new code.

Somebody can help me?

Comment: " I cleaned the project and build it again but eclipse show me always the old code" and "When i open the files with the editor it shows me the new code." see how these two don't match?

Comment: if you debug, you get the code you are running. so, did you compile and deploy your new code before debugging?